# Search for in a delimited string column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, split

I have a search string like this: 'value1,value4,value8'

I have a database table with entry's like this:

```
id   |    value
-----+------------------------
1    |    value1,value2,value3
2    |    value3,value4,value9
3    |    value4,value8,value9
4    |    value2,value3,value9
```

Now i'm searching for a way to search all records from the database that contains value1, value4 or value8.

In this example I want records 1, 2 and 3 when I do a select.

I already have a split function that splits my search string into IN VALUES like this: 'value1','value4','value8', but I can't get it to work to select the right records.

Thanks.

Comment: You do know that data is not in 3rd normal form?   Have you considered fixing the data first as then the TSQL syntax is simpler and the query  executes more efficiently?

Comment: Based on you want records 1,2 and 3 then you mean contains value1, value4, OR value8

Comment: You mean a table with all the values and a table referring to the id's of these values?

Comment: A row.  Record 1 does not contain value1, value4, AND value8.  Record 1 contains value1, value4, OR value8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

**Test data**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    id INT,
    value VARCHAR(200)
)
INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES
    (1,'value1,value2,value3'),
    (2,'value3,value4,value9'),
    (3,'value4,value8,value9'),
    (4,'value2,value3,value9')
```

**Split function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@sep char(1), @s varchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn,
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
  )
GO
```

**Query**

```
DECLARE @searchString VARCHAR(100)
SET @searchString='value1,value4,value8'
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        split.s as searchString
    FROM 
        dbo.Split(',',@searchString) AS split
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Table1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM
        dbo.Split(',',Table1.value) AS split
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            CTE
        WHERE
            CTE.searchString=split.s
    )
)
```

**Result**

```
id      value
1       value1,value2,value3
2       value3,value4,value9
3       value4,value8,value9
```

**Edit**

This split function takes in a separator and the `varchar` to split. It is a recursive function that cacluates the start and the end of where the sperator is in the inputted `varchar`. When the start and end is calculated the `substring` is a easy task to perform.

Comment: No problem. If you are fine with the answer the might consider accepting it. And also remember to upvote if you think the answer is good. It gives us all warm-fuzzy feelings

Answer (score 0):

if you have matching values in code and it's going to be static this might work:

```
select * from table where value like '%value1%' and value like '%value4%' and value like '%value8%'
```

This is if you want it to contain all values. If you want it to contain either or then you switch 'and' for 'or'

Edit:

Having values in code you can build the SQL statement dynamically in code.

```
string statement = "select * from table where value like '%value%'";
foreach (string value in collectionOfValues) {
      statement += " and value like '" + value + "'";
}
```

I would of course use SqlParameters instead of putting the value directly in the statement, but you catch my drift.

Comment: The search string I get from code, and is dynamic. So it can be one value or six or whatever. So I must split the search string and make a select statement out of it.

Comment: Did i understand what you wanted by the last edit of my post?

Comment: Yes, I understand. But i'm looking for a solution to do it all in a stored procedure.

Comment: I will look into it, but might i ask why you would prefer doing it in a stored procedure? What advantages are there?

Comment: you might want to use `WHERE ',' + value + ',' LIKE '%,valueX,%'` to avoid false hits. E.g. without the comma's you might otherwise match value48 when looking for value4

Comment: @deroby I do not agree, if you take the string delimited by ',' you could do a string.Split(',') and by that remove all instances of ',' character. The string also does not start with ',' and hence would not match the first and last element in string.

Comment: @BjørnØyvindHalvorsen Correct the split from the search parse does not have commas but the database column has commas.  Like '%value4%' will match value4 and value48.

Comment: @deroby problem is no starting comma on the first and no ending comma on the last.

Comment: @Blam i was referring to if he did a split in C# code, not in database.

Comment: @BjørnØyvindHalvorsen The context was split on the input string. If you meant split on database column then that really changes things up and urge you to post a complete answer based on that.  If the split of the database column is done in C# then every row would need to be retrieved to C#.

Comment: @Blam, He uses a database split function, where the values he is splitting comes from code. I simply suggested that he'd split his filter in code, and create the query to database in code, instead of in a procedure. If you read my answer you see what i mean. I am in no way trying to suggest to split database columns in code.

Comment: @BjørnØyvindHalvorsen OK, your response to deroby referred to "the string" twice and you were referring to two different string so you can see how I misinterpreted.  But you do agree Like '%value4%' will match value4 and value48 basically breaks everything?

Answer (score 0):

To get what you're asking for, I think you either need to insert your separated results (without single quotes) into a temporary table, or make your splitting function return a table. Then you can say:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3 
FROM table1
WHERE value in (select * from #values)
```

OR

```
WHERE value in (select * from dbo.StringSplitFunc(...))
```

depending on which approach you take.